# Do I have to create Sonatype JIRA ticket when publishing an upgraded version of an existing library to maven central?

Tags: java, jira, sonatype, maven-central

I'm trying to publish a upgraded version of an existing library in maven central
Do I need to create a JIRA for every version upload to maven central?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, is it today on sonatype and automatic several days after.